# Java Script Placement and Unresponsive HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I am creating a website for my friend and was able to fix most of the things in general. However, Im having a problem with the mobile version and the javasrcipt for the site. H

Here is the first edited try that I did wherein the java script for the smooth scrolling of different section is completely working along with when you emulate an iphone in your browser, it has that hidden menu on the top.

Click to see here : [www.jakenallas.com/testRico](http://www.jakenallas.com/testRico)

After a couple of revisions, I think i messed it up somewhere in the CSS or the javascript at some point. I'm trying to get the same scrolling effect from before, the straight lined images for the portfolio section and the hidden menu when you go to mobile.

I believe that I must manage to fix the mobile css but I have no idea on where to start.

Here is the link on how it looks like now. [www.jakenallas.com/testRico9](http://www.jakenallas.com/testRico9)

In addition to my query, I've seen errors in the javascript inspect element in the brrowser saying this > “uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function” in JavaScript"

I hope you could help me fix this.

Thank in advance.

Regards,
Jake

Comment: This question is basically, "my stuff is broken, can somebody fix it?" - and not what this site is really for. You took a free theme and tried to pull it off, but it's not a single question. It's like, an entire semester of questions. Good luck.

Comment: What is messed is your javascript code, CSS has nothing to do with smooth scrolling as far as I know